# Setting up a cookie

Tags: cookies, setcookie

i want to start a new cookie in my website by taking the number from i
example: testsite.com/?i=22

I use this code in my index.php

```
setcookie('i', $_GET['i'], 0, '/', "testsite.com",0,0);
```

The problem is that i need this cookie to be used in the whole website, not just in the index.php
If i press the link testsite.com/?i=22 it's not a problem it's start a new cookie but if i go to another page (register, login etc) the cookie disappear...
How can i make it to be valid for all pages of my website?

Comment: you writed ".com" twice in the domain parameter?

Comment: no i don't i write it here by mistake, sorry

Comment: what do you mean by "the cookie disappears"? Your browser sends it in the request headers? Was it received in the previous page?

Comment: I receive it in the index page when i go to the link testsite.com/?i=22, but if i go to another page after that, there is no cookie....

Answer (score 1):

may be you should try to put the $_GET value into some variable, ex. $val = $_GET["i"], and then use the $val in the cookie.

Comment: i try it, it's the same

Comment: try to use $_SESSION instead of cookies

Comment: try to use it like this `setcookie('i', $_GET['i'], 0);` if you are loosing it on other pages